# Are there any reasonable paying jobs one can get without a college degree?

Tags: job-search

I'm a student in college currently pursuing a degree in mental health, but I was wondering whether anyone could offer me job suggestions which pay reasonably well. I'm 19 years old and would not mind a job that was tedious or "boring" as long as it does not require making phone calls or dealing with customers. A sort of background office job?

I do not have any experience in the workforce, but I have volunteered at churches and libraries and homeless shelters. I would prefer to hit the ground with a running start if possible because I need to make payments for my house. A desk or office like position would be preferable. Fetching coffee and items for others, filing paperwork, transcribing, making orders of items, typing out letters or emails, taking notes, shelving? Is there any job which meets a description like this which won't require actual up front contact with the customers? Or very little, at least? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you looking for a temporary job while pursuing your college degree? Or do you want to change your career path?

Comment: Please state the country you are, answers can be perfect for one country will be useless/incorrect for another

Comment: If you got the talent and the opportunit some jobs will pay much more than you needs (or even deserves) in politics, sports, show business, etc

Comment: consider surgical tech, physicians assistant, truck driver, construction, warehousing, etc

Answer (score 15):

The best kept secret in the workforce is

> Trades pay extremely well.

Plumbers, electricians, HVAC technicians and other skilled trades all pay very well, and are in constant demand. They are going to command take home pay easily comparable to the average university educated worker.

This is assuming you are in a first world country.

Comment: Those kind of jobs do pay well, but they have one caveat - the good salary comes after you have paid your dues working for someone else at a fairly minimal salary, and then start your own company and get some word out. Usually after 2-4 years or so, at least around here.

Comment: You're correct, but op doesn't have a trade cert or experience.

Comment: As a counterpoint to the 'pay your dues' comment. Robot programming as a trade is very easy to get into, and it's very easy to move up in pay. Typically wages start around 2x minimum, and cap out around 4-5x minimum. The demand for workers is massive, the certifications are optional (though they increase your pay) and you don't have to understand much about programming at all. The work conditions are not so great though, long hours, lots of travel, very little opportunity to further your education.

Comment: It's the typical country based answer. Those jobs will not be good in the third world (even in the west)

Comment: @jean By 'Western' I mean "not third world".

Comment: @DJClayworth so for disambiguation you shold use "first world", "Western world" has lots of definitions (with differents levels of flaws, depending on who is asking)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a QA engineer. I've been doing this job for more than 13 years.
I haven't finished uni, don't have a degree. I did go to university (Computer Sciences) but dropped out in my final year and never graduated.
I make around 2.5k euro in hand in an eastern EU country (which is a lot more than my peers with a Uni degree make in other fields of work in my country). To put that in perspective, if I had a degree, I'd make 600 Eu more because of tax exemptions. Last year I made around 9k/mo working as a contractor in another EU country.

Most jobs I applied for do ask for a degree, but will gladly accept you if you can provide relevant experience in the field. And I have plenty.

A friend of mine went to music school (got a music school degree, scholarship at Juilliard), played for big bands for many years, taught music, then decided to change his life after playing the violin for 20 years. I helped him with studying, preparing interviews and landing a starter job in the industry. Now he makes around 8k/mo as a contractor in Belgium.

My recipe: never stop learning. Always seek ways to improve yourself, study on your own (at least a couple hours a day) and you can pick up software testing as a profession. It's well paying and true specialists are hard to come by. Requirements to get in the field are low: you need patience, critical thinking, an analytical mind and good understanding of how software works, at least at an user level. Then sky is the limit. Just like any job, you can choose to specialise on a particular field of work, like security or usability and make a lot of money, or become a general practitioner and make a lot of money.

Another way to get your foot in the door for an interview is to get a certification like ISTQB foundations, which is trivial to get if you study their materials online.

I've rarely had to deal with customers, but part of my job is to be their advocate when software is developed, so I have to profile and know my users, to be able to be a good tester. So I have to empathise with them but not actually talk to them :D.

If you are interested, I'd recommend starting with Cem Kaner's "Black Box Software Testing" courses on youtube (search for TestingEducation channel) and then follow up with the ISTQB "dogma" materials (you can find the Software Testing Foundations course online in PDF format, or can enroll for the certification). They should be enough to land you a starter job as a Junior QA Engineer.

If you decide testing software is not enough for you, you can always advance to developing it, a lot of junior testers join companies and then become developers or sysops/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Good paying jobs requiring little to no experience tend to be either dangerous or unsavoury. So most office positions do not apply except cleaner.

In my time as a cleaner I made more money than most office workers, the time was usually at night and the pay was great. It was a pretty easy job if you don't mind cleaning toilets and floors. Office cleaning tends to be a lot better than public buildings where people treat the facilities very badly.

Apart from that most jobs are physical, labouring if you're in a city, or my personal favourite, forestry if you're in a rural area or near one. As a forestry worker I made large amounts of money, but you need to be fit and strong to succeed as the best paying jobs are paid by how much you do rather than how many hours, so I made a couple of k a week, but some made only a couple of hundred.

Comment: Cleaners being paid more than the office employees is highly irregular, to say the least

Comment: @Our_Benefactors He's a good cleaner.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors nope, it's an unsavoury job most people don't want and think is beneath them, it's pretty highly paid in the first world, much more than a grunt office worker, and a cleaner can service several clients. The trick like most jobs is to work for yourself rather than a cleaning company.

Comment: @Kilisi We must have different life experiences. Typically cleaner positions in my area are posted at around $12-15/hr while office workers are rarely less than $18/hr, a fairly significant gap at the entry level. Not to mention the career prospects are generally much better for the office worker.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors yes must be different experience... were you working for yourself or for a cleaning company? The cleaning company typically charges a lot more than 15 an hour because it's just not viable at that. I made 25 an hour and that was almost 2 decades ago so it should be much hjigher now... and I was undercutting the companies. Career prospects don't matter, op isn't taking it up as a career. New Zealand though, unsure where you are located. My current country they make the equivalent of $1 US an hour and whatever they can steal (third World).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a paid internship in any field if you have or you can learn basic skills related.

I studied Finances and also Computers, but before I graduated, I needed a job and what I found it was a job as a web designer. It wasn't well paid, but it was a chance to make some money and have a first job.

I searched on google for internships in your field of interest and it seems you have options there: https://www.indeed.com/q-Mental-Health-Internship-jobs.html, https://www.indeed.com/q-Behavioral-Health-Internship-jobs.html.

You also can start writing pieces of advice on a blog. If you will have followers, you can make money from that. Photography, graphic design can be hobbies that can bring you money.

Also, if your communication skills are good, you can try freelance jobs in HR.